# On the boundaries of "not-constructive" questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, specific-question, not-constructive

Earlier today I saw the following question being asked on SO: [Algorithm improvement for Coca-Cola can shape recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168686/algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-shape-recognition). In my opinion a very interesting question based on its subject matter and well written as well.

However, at the end of all information, the original question ( [the specific revision I'm referring to can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10168686/2) ) asked the following:

> I'd like to get some ideas to improve my project (not asking for general case shape recognition, just specifically for cans like here). I spent quite a bit of time on it, and would have loved to spend more, but I didn't have time or courage (or maybe both) to do it until now, probably because I'm not sure how I can improve it, and that's why I'm here asking for help. This could be improvements on this one algorithm, or totally different algorithms that may be more adapted. Any language is welcome, even if I'd prefer more C++ / OpenCV specifics or maybe Java, but this is overall more of a talk about algorithms than language-specific stuff.

Even though I like the topic and find the question as such interesting, based on this last section I voted to close as "not-constructive". I my opinion, with the question as it was, it would essentially allow for a discussion, a debate and a whole myriad of possibly correct answers targetting too broad a scope.

From the moment of casting this vote however, it has been questioned by various commenters and the OP stating such things as:

- *"This is a perfect question for this site."*
- *"This is a great interesting question."*
- *"brilliant question..........."*

as well as various other comments in support of the question and questioning the vote to close. In fact, the question has gathered quite a number of upvotes by now, which I can even understand.

I can see where they are coming from, but if I would be particularly negative I would say "it's a non-constructive question in excellent disguise". Perhaps more suited for a forum setting rather than a Q&A.

**TL;DR**

I'm not here to get the question closed and even hesitated to ask this question here. I would readily accept that my interpretation of "not constructive" is too strict. But is it?

At which point does a question become "not constructive"? (I guess the answer simply is "when the community decides it is"?) And am I complete off-target in my assessment?

Comment: To the mods who re-opened the question. Thank you. And thank you especially for restoring faith in the system.

Comment: @EMS out of respect for the DSP SE, I should point out that the question was never actually _closed_, but rather moved to the [DSP](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) site. Give the other sites some credit, SO isn't the center of the universe.

Comment: Sure, but the OP mentioned that in less than 10 hrs on SO, the question received a lot of useful answers. Meanwhile, at that time, it had received none at DSP. My aesthetic taste / experience is that you don't get good implementational advice at DSP, but it's great for understanding the theory better. I think SO was right for *this* question, but many others are right for DSP.

Comment: I don't think the question is non-constructive in the least.  I'm leaning toward off-topic -- SO is about programming, and computer science != programming, as this question clearly shows.  If the question was "I'm trying to implement such-and-such particular algorithm in less CPU time", it'd be completely on-topic.  But discussions of image recognition algorithms aren't, not even discussions of which have higher complexity.

Comment: @BenVoigt I back then felt that the initial revision of the question would lead to a brainstorm session where one could fling solutions at a wall to see what would stick. As such I thought the end result would be not constructive. I have since (partially via this question) revised my viewpoint slightly and see where you're coming from. I still don't think this is a good question though, but I'm largely outnumbered and perhaps stubborn. ;)

Comment: @Bart: I think brainstorming by non-experts is a common outcome of interesting but off-topic questions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> I'm not here to get the question closed and even hesitated to ask this question here. I would readily accept that my interpretation of "not constructive" is too strict. But is it?

Yes.

> In my opinion a very interesting question based on its subject matter and well written as well.

Primarily because he *didn't* just post the title and that last section, he described, *in detail*, what he was trying to do, what he'd tried, and the problems he'd encountered. The vast, *vast* majority of "not constructive" questions fall into that category by lacking this effort.

Can and will it still attract lousy answers? Sure. It's an interesting question, popular, and therefore prone to attract folks who just want to be part of the action, even if they've nothing to contribute. I've seen this happen to the most clearly-written, objective questions imaginable, questions where the answers could be easily tested for accuracy in *seconds*... And aren't. Down-vote those answers. Flag them, if they're bad enough. Leave comments chiding the answerers for not bothering to put in even a fraction of the effort the asker did in asking.

There are countless questions asked on SO every day that are boring, lazy, and completely thoughtless. The [Don't Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) portion of the FAQ does a pretty good job of laying out the hallmarks of a real "not constructive" question. Close as such for those reasons.

But please, **don't** close a question when it gains unwanted attention for being *too good!*

Comment: Love the last sentence. Heavy traffic means a question may need *protection*, not *closure*.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for this answer. I really like the point of view, although I don't follow it fully. I don't think the question was being "too good". It was very interesting and informative, but the ultimate question asked was not that good IMHO. (Although we might and probably do disagree). But I can agree that I might have been too strict in my evaluation. Which was why I asked this question in the first place. So thanks a lot once again.

Comment: I'd add that after seeing this, I will probably not risk writing "interesting" or "quality" questions, and will just fall back to what seems to be expected from me : plain, boring, short, dull down-to-earth questions.

Comment: @Bart: my best advice is that you evaluate questions holistically: don't fixate on a single line or paragraph, read the entire question and re-phrase it in your own voice... Then decide whether or not *your* question is constructive. This technique also helps if you need to edit the original question for clarity. The goal here is to produce the best question possible, not shut down anything that doesn't exactly fit a pre-defined template.

Comment: Thanks for the post @Shog9, I really appreciate it. This makes me think I should maybe follow the formal process to request to un-move the question. But after what I've seen with the Meta-gang, I'm just afraid to get -Infinity downvotes if I dare only think about it.

Comment: @linker: if you want it un-migrated, I'm happy to do that. [Yoda's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129423/on-the-boundaries-of-not-constructive-questions/129437#129437) seems to indicate that DSP will welcome it as well, so looks like you have your pick of sites.

Comment: @Shog9 I ultimately still am more inclined to say that (at least part of) the responsibility for the attracted kind of answers lies with the OP. However, I do feel after all the discussions and opinions that I should perhaps have commented first to the OP, clarifying my point of view. Perhaps, as you say, telling him about "my question" and how I would have phrased it, all to avoid the problems I foresaw. I'll keep this in mind on future questions.

Comment: @Shog9, yes I feel it would be more at its place in SO, and I believe the reasons are good: I really want a **quality** answer, and I believe I would be more enclined to have great answers on SO. Image processing and general programming are far from being incompatible, I already started getting some **quality** answers after barely 10 hours, so I'm sure I'd get something really good after some time, and this would improve the community a lot.

Comment: @linker Don't have too glum a view of SO or MSO. Especially on MSO we're all an opinionated bunch. Ultimately all with a similar goal. To make SO better. In fact, the whole reason I asked my question here is to get opinions. Even if it would have meant that I would have been shot down. The results of discussions here might not always be to our liking, but I'd rather have that than no opportunity to discuss at all.

Comment: @Bart I totally understand that you're doing your best to make SO a better place, and I can understand that you had your opinion on the topic. I'm still new to the site so still learning how all of this works together, but I really felt my question did fit well for SO, especially since I took the time to go through the FAQ like 10 times to make sure I wasn't OT.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks, I feel this is the right decision for the community on this passionating topic.

Comment: @SO: And yet, there wasn't a single line of code.

Comment: .. Just like the FAQ says there doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 12):

I don't believe your interpretation is incorrect.  In making edits to a question, we do as much as we can to **respect the author**.

In this case, the author has laid out a very interesting piece on *what* they've done (in fact, the majority of the question is about that).

However, the *actual question* is "how can I improve on this"?  That makes the question "not constructive".  As you've read it (and as I have) there are many ways this can be done, each with varying degrees of effect, and people tend to get worked up over this kind of thing, hence the close reason.

Fortunately [we have a site for people who have working code that they wish to be reviewed for improvements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

However, I'd emphatically state that this is really a question that should be moved to [Digital Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) as they *specialize* in doing *exactly* this kind of work, and while this has been upvoted heavily here, the answers are *really* quite lacking.  The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168923/50776) isn't even an answer, it just asks another question (for the most part).

Comment: the question is not "how can i improve on this", but "how can i improve my algorithm in OpenCV to solve the 4 points where my algorithm fails".

Comment: The code review site doesn't correspond at all to the question: I implemented the algorithm correctly, the problems I encountered do not come from a wrong design choice. This is about the algorithm itself and what I did wrong in the process to make it slow and fail on some use cases.

Comment: @linker It seems like you could contribute a lot to the dsp site with this question, not to mention get more qualified responses. Why not take the question there?

Comment: I'd like to understand why a question like "how can i improve my algorithm in OpenCV to solve the 4 points where my algorithm fails" doesn't fit on SO, because if it's the case we should seriously update the FAQ. To me it fits as well on SO than on DSP, I even saw a comment saying this shouldn't be here because this is machine learning. But why do we have a machine-learning tag with 1k+ posts then?

Comment: If there should be no intersection between all sites on stackexchange like what you seem to say, there should be some serious cleanup in the tags.

Comment: @linker I didn't make the statement that there shouldn't be an intersection between all sites on Stack Exchange.  That's nearly impossible.  There are some places where the question has a *better* fit, however, which is the statement I made.

Comment: I see the question has been moved. How does move work? This doesn't seem right. I've hesitated for a long time to join Overflow because nearly all my friends told me that all interesting questions get closed or moved. I guess that wasn't so far away from the truth.

Comment: @linker FYI, from my experience questions are often being migrated to give them a better chance at a more appropriate SE. An attempt to be helpful rather than harmful. Although you can always object to it should you wish to do so.

Comment: How do you make a formal objection?

Comment: This didn't really need "a better chance" as I was already getting very interesting answers.

Comment: @linker Yes, it did.  It had four close votes on it for it being "Not Constructive".  One more and you would have gotten *no* more answers.

Comment: But maybe these 4 close votes were also not constructive. I would have gotten most likely interesting answers if you had just given the question maybe as much as one day.

Comment: @linker That argument doesn't really work.  You'd have to find the people that cast the close vote, find their reasons, etc.  That's just not how the system works.  The Stack Exchange sites rely heavily on the collaboration of the community to maintain quality.  Your question failed to meet the current standards that are clearly established.  Why are you so dedicated to seeing the question on Stack Overflow?  Your pursuance of the location of this question hints at a lack of concern for a quality answer, and for the promotion of the question, which is not a good basis for asking a question.

Comment: If the question is not constructive on SO, then it is not constructive on every SE site and shouldn't be migrated anywhere. It might certainly be a better fit on DSP, but if you were convinced that it is not constructive it shouldn't be migrated.

Comment: @Fabian That's not necessarily true.  The close reasons don't always translate exactly across sites.  Also, some sites are, how shall we say, *more tolerant* of certain questions because they are more constructive *in their domain* as opposed to Stack Overflow, which is the *general domain*.

Comment: I agree with @Fabian. Every argument above that the question should be moved is frustratingly tenuous. The original questions asked 4 specific points about a specific implementation for a specific task. This questions is absolutely as constructive as all the questions where someone asks "which way to sort this list is best in Python?" or the equivalent. It has no direct, objective answer unless you assume some definition of "best", and yet we upvote, accept, and happily answer such questions all the time. In this case, the only difference is that the author did a lot of research first.

Comment: I not only did research on it, but explained my whole process of thought and what I wanted to improve. I spent more than an hour to write it. And yet I see people who just copy/paste their homework who don't get moved and get upvoted...

Comment: @linker: [Stack Overflow is not a "do my homework for me" site.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128572/102937)

Comment: @linker: It's great that you spent time and effort on the question. But spending time and effort is simply not how we decide what questions to keep. Your question ultimately asks for people's opinions, with little objective way to measure whether an answer is correct. There is no one right answer, and someone answering has no way to know that their answer is right. That's simply not allowed here. As others have stated, other sites are generally a bit more lenient about "good subjective" questions. These rules keep SO focused on solving real problems.

Comment: @Nicol: I gotta disagree with this - it may not be *trivial* to test the correctness of an answer, but it is certainly *possible*. It's a bit grating to see folks picking on a couple of sentences out of a detailed, multi-page question, when the problems with them can be more than mitigated by the context. Every day, I see questions that consist of little more than, "What's a good algorithm for..." without *any* indication of thought or research on the part of the asker, much less detail on what he has tried, or how it has failed. *Those* damnable questions need this sort of attention.

Comment: @Nicol I also disagree with you. linker's question does not ask for an opinion anymore than run of the mill "which sort method is best for my Python dictionary" questions do. He spells out specific points of the algorithm to work on, and wants concrete implementation ideas in OpenCV for C++. There are a number of narrow-scope, code-specific answers that are appropriate for linker's question. Multiple objective solutions can exist. The whole "not appropriate for this site" and "not objective" or "not narrow scope" are *way way way way* too subjective to allow moderators to close questions.

Comment: @EMS Your focus (even within your comments on the original question) seems to be too much on the moderators within SO. For as far as I can tell, there were 4 users who voted to close. A moderator finally migrated it to what he believed was a more appropriate site. Sure, you can disagree with that. But in the particular handling of this question I think the moderators have at the very least been trying to be helpful and don't deserve the amount of criticism you level at them. If you disagree with me, feel free to downvote though. Or even write a constructive answer if you like.

Comment: @Bart -- I appreciate your point, but I do disagree with you very much. If 100+ folks upvote a question, and 4 people can cause it to be closed/migrated, the moderators deserve *a lot* of criticism.

Comment: Note that I got 7 interesting answers in 10 hours, out of which a few were of quality. But on DSP? None !

Comment: @EMS, why the moderators? Or do you mean to say "the moderators put up the 5 vote boundary, therefor I critique the moderators"? Just trying to clarify this.

Comment: Yes, the choice to respect such a tiny boundary, the choice to interpret only the votes to close and not contextualize them in the larger scenario, and the perpetual dialog on meta where cognitive dissonance appears to reign king (e.g. the claims that this question was not constructive and/or didn't have well-defined answers are flamboyantly weak, yet are being used to justify that the decision to migrate/close was a good one).

Comment: I'm most disappointed with the meta process, which I've never observed to work correctly. When a question gets closed, that is strong empirical evidence that it won't be re-opened. Do people really believe that ~4 close votes is such a strong predictor of a bad question? That doesn't seem statistically reasonable to me. You're claiming that a small sample opinion (the close votes) is a better estimator of question quality than hundreds of other user votes. Bayes would be sad.

Comment: @EMS, Yes but what can you do? As long as I know I'm not the only one to believe that my question was of **quality**, like you think, and like maybe 99% of the people who visited the questions, I'm happy. For the remaining 1%, I feel I cannot be of much help if they value more homework-type questions, than real questions with a deep thought process and a well-defined scope.

Answer (score 4):

I have posted this question in hope to get good and constructive answers about how to improve my system. I don't really see in what manner this is non-constructive, there seem to be all components of a constructive question here :

- A specific algorithm that I wish to improve on.
- A specific language and even library I wish to use.
- A lot of details about what I want to improve on.

I see a lot of questions labelled as "Help me improve my code", or "Make my code run faster", that for most of them don't give any direction on how we can help them, yet there is no request for close.

In my opinion it is not because the problem is slightly more complex that this is not constructive. If I understand correctly, SO is a website to solve programming problems, and this is indeed a programming problem with a reduced scope even if I did not post any code.

By the way I have updated the main scope of the question, please give me more details if you think this is not constructive.

> As an attempt to comply with those who consider this
>   "non-constructive", here is a simple reduced form of my question: can
>   you help me improve my specific algorithm, using exclusively OpenCV
>   features, to resolve the four specific issues mentionned? Don't tell
>   me that it's less constructive than "Improve this SQL query" or "Make
>   my program faster" or so, please. Sorry if that limits the discussion,
>   but this seems to be what a group of a few people want.

Comment: I have lots of code I'd love somebody else to improve as I lack the time to do so; just SO is not the place to ask for that sort of help. Your edit to the question does a bit of a better job, but because your question lacks code and is mostly high-level it doesn't exactly appeal to the core of SO. Basically, you've given us nothing to fix...

Comment: What do you mean I've given nothing to fix? There are all the details about the algorithm/workflow i'd like to improve, on which language, and on what characteristics i'd like to improve. Explain please.

Comment: I didn't see any code listed, perhaps your data structures are trash and the code you have currently would do fine. We have no way to know.

Comment: FAQ: """if your question generally covers …
a specific programming problem
a software algorithm
software tools commonly used by programmers
practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession"""  it seems to me all 4 are respected by my question: 1) specific programming problem: improving coca cola can detection, 2) algorithm: generalized hough transform, 3) openCV, 4) recognizing coca cola cans is very practical and quite unique.

Comment: I understand the FAQ and its finer points; again, you've talked about code but we don't see any of it. *It is very hard to improve code you cannot see.* You're looking for higher level help which doesn't always fit on SO and often sets the bar higher for being Constructive. If you'd have provided profiling data or something (poor performance due to allocation, etc), perhaps it would be a better fit. A good test to see if your question is constructive is to see the answers it receives...which are not great: this is indicative of the question needing another home.

Comment: Why do you speak about code? The FAQ explicitely says you don't necessarily need code. Please let me know a valid reason that agrees with the FAQ.

Comment: You asked us to improve code without providing any code...hence 5 individuals (I was not one of them, and likely would have left your question alone) with close privileges believed your question to be Non-Constructive. This jives with the FAQ. Not every question is a good fit for SO.

Comment: So a suggestion would be to update the FAQ. Read my question again, I'm not asking to improve my code, I'm asking to improve my algorithm, and this is totally acceptable.

Comment: Your algorithm may not have been why your program is slow, we'll never know. Besides, casperOne has already pointed your question to a more appropriate site to get the level of help required for improving your algorithm.

Comment: You're avoiding my question, I wasn't asking to improve my code, but my algorithm. Speed was not the most important.

Comment: Algorithm == code, and if it does not then it does not belong on SO and I would vote accordingly; I believe I've answered your question.

Comment: Algorithm == workflow. Code is only a consequence of an algorithm. Even the FAQ is explicit about it. I believe discussion is not possible.

Comment: If you don't believe code is the most important part of an algorithm, SO will likely be an bothersome place. Workflow/discussionesque questions are best served on other sites, certainly similar questions exist on SO and do fine; yours did not. This is all covered in the FAQ and on meta posts about the same.

Comment: I believe code is the core of the algorithm for sure, but why does the FAQ say you don't necessarily need code, while you're saying the opposite?

Comment: If this is just a question of "code" I'll just repost it with some code then, hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: I'm saying the standard by which a question is judged is much higher if you do not provide code. Questions without code are more likely to be a bad fit for SO. We want to answer interesting questions, but we want there to be *an* answer (or a reasonable facsimile of "an"). Besides, since the core of your question relates to a DSP algorithm it should reside on the DSP site. If the core of your question was the *code behind your algorithm* then I would agree that SO is the best fit. Does this distinction make sense?

Comment: Why is there a machine-learning tag then? I can repost this with some code for sure !

Comment: There are plenty of sharp folks who would love to help fix problems in your code which is limiting the performance of your algorithm on SO. There are (maybe, never been there) plenty of sharp folks who would love to help design an accurate and well performing DSP algorithm on DSP.

Comment: To whoever wrote "algorithm == code", thank you for giving me something to laugh about. I personally have helped answer algorithm performance and design questions on SO many times, and lots of others answered the same questions, gave them upvotes, and never complained. It didn't even occur to any of us that such questions could *possibly* not be right for SO. The only difference here is that this OP did a ton of great research first. If the question had been 1 paragraph about Hough transforms, no one would have said anything about it.

Comment: I think some moderators just made a very subjective choice, but sadly they will never admit it. If you read the FAQ, my question matched ALL of it, and nobody has been able to give me a valid reason except some vague answers.

Comment: @EMS, you're free to answer any question you'd like regardless of its fit on SO. I was pointing out why this particular question received close votes in spite of its popularity (again, I did not vote either way). At the end of the day, code wins on SO.

Comment: Again, look at the FAQ and update it if code is the only thing that matters on SO. sigh...

Comment: @sixlettervariables Yeah, I know I can answer the question. But why should I bother to answer questions on SO if very well-researched, thorough, widely useful questions that are specifically about implementation and algorithms won't be allowed to stay up here? Saying that "code wins" does nothing but avoid all of linker's good points. Update the FAQ to say that non-code questions will be judged at a higher standard, and then clearly spell out the specifics of that higher standard, or else admit that code is not necessary and that linker's question was totally valid as-is.

Comment: It seems silly to give your users, especially us who answer more than we ask, a *dis-incentive* to ask or answer thorough, on-topic questions. This moderator opinion nonsense has to change or SO will just morph into a homework question site, much like what happens at mathoverflow, where the moderators are even worse and will close things for purely aesthetic reasons. The density of disguised textbook problems there is very high, and that will happen here because opinionated moderators act like a pressure to force out good, research-quality questions.

Comment: @EMS: Perhaps the FAQ understates the importance of code (maybe it should be in red), but it is even more important now that StackExchange has grown beyond just SO. Gray area questions get more community scrutiny by definition so the FAQ doesn't need to be updated. Regardless, I can't update the FAQ, but I've let you know what my experience is and why folks voted as they did. I encourage you to keep asking and answering questions so you can acquire the rep to vote to close/reopen as well (then you too can tend the garden of questions on SO and make decisions someone will find unpopular).

Comment: This is a totally silly argument. The FAQ exists to serve as a fixed guideline for the extra scrutiny you mention. Saying that you don't need to update it just because traffic is higher implies that because of higher traffic, moderator opinions are more important than experienced user opinions, and that the FAQ is free to totally diverge from the actual criteria that are promised to the users that their questions will be judged by.

Comment: Also, I disagree that the FAQ underemphasizes code. Code *should not be emphasized*. Code is only a minor part of the learning exchanges that SO is intended to service. Questions without code, when well-researched, are often *the best and most appropriate questions.* I agree that poorly researched non-code questions are not good, but that is a straw man that no one here is trying to defend.

Comment: I agree with @EMS, but I'll keep my mouth shut, since it seems what the mods want me to do.

Comment: The OP wanted *DSP algorithm design* help, and not *algorithm coding* help. I guess I'll grant you that the FAQ doesn't specify why questions are migrated, but it sufficiently handles why questions are closed. When folks disagree they come to meta. Process works. What I don't understand is ill will towards the moderators...the three who've answered this question appear to be trying to help?

Comment: Once again, I disagree. The need for all of it to be contextualized in OpenCV for C++ definitely makes it algorithm design *and* coding. If it was nothing but a vague question about algorithms, then I'd agree. But here it was specifically "what are some specific ways to improve *this* algorithm (Hough transform methods) in *this* library (OpenCV) with *this* language (C++). See my [other comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129424/183600) about the need for moderator criticism.

Comment: @EMS: so it was a do my coding for me question instead of an algorithm design question? The moderator you criticized migrated the question to a site designed to answer the perceived question at hand instead of allowing it to be closed! That seems pretty helpful to me.

Comment: Nope it wasn't a do-my-coding for me question. It was a "what are expert opinions about the right places to look specifically in these libraries" question. Outrageously different than asking someone to do coding for you. An answer to this question would involve pointing out the appropriate feature extraction methodologies in OpenCV (not explicitly coding them for the OP), which involves specific discussion of the code and which approaches are more efficient.

Comment: The *idea of* feature extraction would be appropriate for DSP, not the *how-to*. This is a question asking "how do I efficiently extract features using this language and library." This is not at all asking for someone to write the code, just point to the places that library functions are used for this and leave it up to the OP to build and test them. It's an implementational detail (hence not really for DSP) but not a write-the-code-that-will-do-this detail, hence not a do-my-coding-for-me question.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I just saw this and your (excellent) question. I vote to close questions pretty aggressively, but I think (especially with your edit) you did plenty to bring the question in the "specific programming problem" domain. Yes, it will attract some low-quality answers, but lots of questions do.

Comment: @agf thanks, I'm glad you find the question interesting ! I've done as much as possible to make it fit in the SO spirit which is why I was confused when it was moved.

Answer (score 2):

As a [top opencv contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opencv/topusers), I have my own take on this subject so please be patient with me as I may provide a different view of the situation:

Obviously, this question has received a ridiculous amount of up votes on other sites, and there's a reason for it: **it's an interesting problem** and **it was well written** by someone who seems to have an *above-the-average* knowledge in OpenCV. All that plus the fact that **we were all brain-washed by Coca-Cola** since medieval times, led that question to receive more up votes than everyone else (at the moment of this writing) that has ever contributed to the OpenCV tag (besides myself) on Stackoverflow.

*A side note*: as some of you may have noticed, it's not fair to these guys, so I think it would be cool if someone posted a thread to debate whether we should really preserve up votes when moving questions from one site to another.

Back to the subject: the OP of that question pointed out (somewhere here) that **the purpose of the question is not** *how can I improve on this* (talking about code), **but** *how can I improve my algorithm in OpenCV*. The reality is: either a program solves a problem, or it doesn't, and his current approach doesn't respect the constraints of the project.

With that in mind, consider this: **OpenCV is not just another programming library**, it's a fantastic framework for [Computer Vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision) - **a field of study** within Computer Science,  that involves other fields of science such as Artificial Intelligence, Machine Learning, Mathematics, Physics, Signal Processing and others - developed by awesome researchers in these areas. When you are building applications with OpenCV you are using a lot more than just your programming skills in C/C++.

What I am trying to say is: as the question aims to find a better set of algorithms, a new approach to really solve **that complex computer vision task**, IMHO, **the question should either be moved to some other place or it will get closed** for 2 reasons:

- **1st**: it's simply **too localized** for Stackoverflow. It requires a lot more than programming experience in C/C++ to answer it successfully (for reasons I explained earlier);
- **2nd**: what the OP is really saying is: *I need a solution to this complex research problem*, but the thing is that [Stackoverflow is not your personal research assistant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128553#128553).

What I think that most people don't understand is that solving this type of exercise takes a lot of time and testing of several different approaches. If the OP is not willing to share what the code he has written so far, it is highly unlikely that any of us are going to start from scratch and just to be able to tell him which algorithms do better at certain points of the application. Not going to happen. In it's current form, the question is better suited to freelancer.com.

Comment: I don't think the question of "fairness" has anything to do here, it's not my fault if my question was upvoted so much, it's the community who decided this. 1st: if we consider that every problem that requires "programming experience" is too localized for SO, we're in trouble. 2nd: i don't need a solution to any complex research problem, i've already gotten very relevant and quality answers on this specific problem. I agree that it would fit equally well on DSP (or the upcoming image processing on area 51), but it also fits very well on SO with the current FAQ.

Comment: And I think you're misunderstanding my question: i'm not asking that anyone starts from scratch to tell me which algorithms do better at which points, that would be way OT ! Look at the answers I received, which focus on the specific problem I gave for some of them, which is exactly what I expected, and it seems to have worked. But my question doesn't have anything to do with your last paragraph.

Comment: I'm not saying it's your fault that it got so many upvotes, I only acknowledge that it did and said why I believe that happened and that I also think it's something we should discuss and maybe prevent in the future. I didn't, at any point, said your question should be closed because it has received an extraordinary amount of up votes.

Comment: About *1st*: your problem requires a lot more than programming experience. It also requires knowledge in a field of science, and that is what makes it localized. We have DSP for that sort of question.

Comment: What makes it require a lot more than programming experience? This is above all a talk about an algorithm, which is encouraged by the FAQ. I'm not interested in a perfect and very complex solution that requires a PhD, I wouldn't have enough knowledge to understand it anyway. I can tell you I have done very little in image processing, only 1 course at university, and have a software engineering background, but definitely not a researcher one. So I don't see why a question that may require a bit more thought than some others would be too localized.

Comment: About my last paragraph, without sharing what you have done so far and let us build & improve upon that, you will get answers that only **seem** to be good, and you will spend a lot of time testing their suggestions. Therefore, the question in it's current form **is not constructive** for Stackoverflow, and is **too localized**, since you are the only one being benefited.

Comment: @linker it certainly doesn't require a PhD in computer vision, but it is highly unlikely that an useful answer is going to come from someone who never invested a proper amount of time being involved researching image processing or computer vision.

Comment: The "non constructive" talk has already been discussed in all possible directions in this thread, I'm not looking to discuss that again as we already have some solid talks as to why this is indeed constructive, I was just replying to the "too localized" question, which I don't understand, it's not because it could fit well in an other website of SE that it doesn't fit as well in SO, it's not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Well I don't know if the guys who posted the top answers to this question have a PhD, but their answers are definitely in the range of what I was looking. I think where you're mistaken is that it's a talk about a specific problem and algorithm, not computer vision in general where this would be OT.

Comment: This question has been mostly discussed by people that have NO experience in the subject of your question. That is why I chose to interfere, since I can offer a unique perspective in the subject. You don't need to worry, though, I don't have the power to close your question alone. Good luck.

Comment: I really appreciate your point, and I'm truly grateful that you take the time to express your concerns, that means a lot and you're truly passionate on the topic. I just disagree with the fact that it's too localized for SO, I think it's perfect since there is a specific problem, a description of what I tried, and what I want to improve. I'm really interested in the image processing website on Area 51 though and already committed to it, I have several questions in mind who would be too broad for SO who will find a home there.

Comment: And if you have an interesting suggestion on the question, I'd be more than happy to read your answer (as long as it stays within the limits of this specific problem of course), it seems like you're very knowledgeable about this topic, at least way more than I am honestly.

Comment: karlphillip, I agree with most of your answer, but disagree with your conclusions. First off, we don't *have* a Computer Vision site - we might well have one *in the future*, but if a question like this isn't getting any worthwhile answers now, on SO, then I don't see much hope for creating one - all of our successful sites have had at least *some* roots in our existing community, and if a question with this much attention can't get an answer then asking it on a much smaller site is pointless. **You're** free to ask a question on CS.SE or DSP.SE if you think there's a better format and venue.

Comment: Second, "too localized" does not mean "I have an obscure problem"... It means "I have a problem that will never apply to anyone else".  Exceedingly localized questions tend to have a problem with being noise, not with being too popular. Oh, and again - if it *was* too localized on SO, it's not gonna get any less localized if I migrate it somewhere else.

Comment: Finally, it's impossible to predict how much effort someone will put into an answer on Stack Overflow. If you don't want to, if the question doesn't interest you, or the reward is too small for the effort, then don't - if no one does, then the question may never be answered. If you *do* want to answer, but for some reason answering on SO offends you, then re-post the question and your answer on whatever site you feel is more appropriate. Heck, write it up and then sit on it until CV.SE launches, if that makes you happy. This is, BTW, the proper way in which to migrate a question without votes.

Comment: @Shog9 It seems kind of obvious that I don't completely understand how Stackoverflow works(or should work), so I apologize. I was under the impression that we were not embracing all things that didn't had a proper home. That question is obviously a Computer Vision challenge, not a C/C++ programming one. Naturally, I was thinking that maybe it was a little bit too obscure for SO. About it being too popular, I already expressed my opinions in the answer on why I think that happened, and I'm willing to bet that the down votes came from people that understand something about CV.

Comment: About your third comment, I really don't think the question have anything to do with I want or my interests, or anything related to me. The question is simply not a good fit for SO for reasons I've stated multiple times around here. If you guys want to keep it because it's popular, fine, I understand that and there is nothing I can do about it. This question has got so much attention because of these discussions that there is in fact a very big chance that Mr. Nice Guy is going to show up and provide an awesome answer, despite everything else.

Comment: I forbid myself to spend more energy on this subject, I apologize in advance, but this was the last time I talked about it. Good luck to you all.

Comment: @karl, you've been around SO long enough to have seen quite a few topics that were allowed, accepted, even *embraced* before getting their own sites. Indeed, one of the best ways of pulling together a new SE site has traditionally been to take a subcommunity on SO and create a site to handle their specific, not-strictly-programming needs, with Server Fault being the first and [mathematica.se] being the most recent. Sites like [cooking.se] with *no* overlap are considerably harder to build. If you ever change your mind and want to continue this discussion, let me know...

Comment: @Shog9 I appreciate your patience and hard work for the growth of our community.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so on the premise that SO is a Q&A site, and that we don't accept questions that will encourage open-ended debate or extended discussion, let's look at the answers so far:

1. [Suggest the OP scan the bottles first and filter them out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168923/915501). OP comments that doing it this way is *probably* not adventitious, for somewhat speculative reasons, and that it could double the processing time.
2. [Suggests several completely new algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10169025/915501). The argument is well cited, but would require a totally different approach from the one the OP started with, and so far there is no concrete evidence that it's superior.
3. [Basically treat the can like a barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10199154/915501). Very interesting, but not well cited, so would require some testing, which makes this choice quite debatable.
4. [Look at shape and highlights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10170895/915501), also not cited or easy to test, i.e. debatable.
5. [Suggests looking for rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10169646/915501). Not cited, OP comments that the usefulness is debatable.
6. [Suggests using a range sensor and neural nets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168866/915501). OK, good ideas, but who said anything about a range sensor? Are we free to suggest any sensing technology we can think of?

The rest of the answers make a lot of interesting suggestions, some involving more hardware, some asking for algorithms which may not exist in OpenCV.

In any case, the top 5 answers all suggest completely different solutions, most of which aren't tested and all of which surely have nuanced advantages and disadvantages, even within the OPs four specific focuses. While we can't blame the OP for bad or open-ended answers, I can't help but think that the question may just be conducive to them.

There is currently a +100 bounty on the question, which may just draw out the "right" answer, but if the answers continue the way they are, determining the correct answer will require every reader to wade through many paragraphs of debate before weighing his particular situation against the various answers and coming his own conclusion. This strikes me as exactly the kind of question we're opposed to, and awarding a bounty to a subjectively superior answer misses the issue even further. Fact is, computer vision is an entire academic discipline with numerous obvious commercial applications. Many in the profession have spent years arguing over the "best" classifier to use in a given situation. To call this thread "specific" in the SO sense overlooks the huge amount of testing and tuning which would be required to rule out even *one* of the suggested solutions, let alone select the *best* one.

In my opinion, to say this question is evolving into anything but an open-ended research blog betrays a lack of experience in machine learning. So while I believe it's an interesting question, and while I would love to learn more about the OPs progress as the project develops, as it's currently evolving I don't think it's appropriate here.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I (think I) said in my answer, but in a more clear way. If the OP edited his question and maybe shared some code, than I would be more inclined to think it could be a constructive question for Stackoverflow. But in its current form I don't think it is. If he share code, than people could improve upon that, but right now any answer that is not build upon concrete proof could be seen as random guesses/speculation.

Comment: Again, I'm not asking about the "best" classifier or anything, but an alternative to boost performance on this specific problem, which is exactly what the top answers are. Sure not all answers make a good point, but I'd like to see a case for a popular question where this is no the case on SO. This is exactly what the bounty is for. I don't understand your argument about the answers "not cited", this is **not** a research project, i don't care about references as long as answers bring a clear and pertinent point.

Comment: @karlphillip why are you still in a deadlock about code? This has already been debated, and it's well explained in the first paragraph of the FAQ that you don't necessarily need code.

Comment: @linker I understand that, but in your case it would make a lot of difference as it would be seen not only as you giving it back to the community, but it would also give us something to build upon, allowing us to really provide useful answers. Right now,  I still can't see a way in which your current question contributes to Stackoverflow. The only one being benefited is you.

Comment: @karlphillip Come on, you're saying im the one this question benefits to, while the only thing you've been looking at for this question is the top opencv list... I think this question actually contributes a lot to the community, by providing a clear concise and detailed problem statement on an interesting topic which is totally in phase with the FAQ. If you're not happy with the answers I can't control that, flag them, downvote them, or even better, propose your own.

Comment: Most of my contributions to OpenCV involves hard data or actual code. I can't provide any of those in this case because it would take me hours to find a proper solution that addresses all the restrictions your question imposed. It's a complex problem, it requires a high level of expertise, and any relevant answer would need hours of research and testing. The way the question is written right now doesn't invite good answers. Therefore, I continue to believe this question is too localized and really doesn't contribute to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @karlphillip It's not because your contributions involve code that all questions need to, again, from the FAQ. Should all questions asking about a more-complex-than-average problem be closed as too localized? Hell no, otherwise you're better off turning stackoverflow into homeworkstackoverflow. Again, I'm not asking for hours of research, testing, etc, I have asked a **specific** problem with **specific** constraints and am asking on how to **improve** my algorithm. Look at some of the answers, they understood very well what was expected here and add a lot of value to the topic.

Comment: @linker No need to put words in my mouth, I never said all questions should share code. It's just that your question invites a (long) theoretical discussion about a complex subject within a field of research few people in this site are prepared to participate. Again, I agree with Shep observations, specially about the usefulness of most (if not all) the answers so far being debatable. It's very difficult to give a useful answer to the problem in the way it was described.

Comment: @karlphillip all popular questions attract noise, answers who are not exactly on topic. Look at some of the other highly voted questions out there. If an answer is not good or not on topic, you should downvote or flag them, that's why we have this stuff. By saying that if a good question hosts a minority of questionnable content (answers) it should be closed, you're just acting like SOPA ! It's these minotiry answers that you should worry about, not the question itself since it's clearly on topic and a good fit for SO.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/493/discussion-between-karlphillip-and-linker)

Comment: `you're just acting like SOPA !` does some extension of Godwin's Law apply here?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question reveals something about SE culture that I have struggled to articulate, but I think is worth noting.

We have a question that the OP acknowledges is well-written, interesting, and useful and on topic for the posted site, yet he felt compelled to vote to close it as "non-constructive," because the poster expressed an openness to algorithmic rather than language-specific solutions.

The SE community seems to be incentivizing people to identify and root out "crap" in almost a pack-like mentality that is IMO getting a little ugly.  The way one signals that they "get it" and are part of the in-group around here is identifying and rooting out crap posts.  See the [meta for the workplace beta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/) for a condensed example of this attitude.

What would be accomplished by closing this post?  Not letting it serve as an example for other posts?  Not allowing users to gain rep with fluffy answers? Not making the internet worse?

Of course, those are visible.  The downside is discouraging users inclined to ask and answer these types of questions.

Comment: Why the need to attach qualifications like a "pack-like mentality" to my vote as "not constructive"? I took the decision based on the direction I personally felt this question would take. (A concern perhaps better worded in the recent answer by @shep) I have no interest in being part of the so called "in-group" and came here to discuss what I thought is an edge-case which had me doubt myself. I still feel there are issues with this question and its answers, and I'm arguably one of the few. I welcome your opinion. I just don't recognize myself in the picture you paint.

Comment: The question **seems** interesting and well written, but it's not a good fit to the site. **Having theorical discussions about something that no one can prove/back up brings little to no value to Stackoverflow**. The user tried to solve the problem and successfully described an approach that doesn't work. Now he is looking for a new approach. At this point I invite everyone to read [Stackoverflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128553#128553).

Comment: I suggest he comes back with a question when he is ready to share something valuable, code or something else that the community can build upon. **I'm not convinced that this question helps anyone but the guy that asked it.**

Comment: @karlphillip you've shown pretty clearly http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130060/183554 that you're above all concerned about your top opencv list and so-called competition (which i have no interest on), you're saying the answers "don't work", how can you say that? The community has already built a lot on this question and for most of them totally in the direction described by the problem, what can you ask more?

Comment: Independently of my personal concerns (if there are any), the fact remains the same: I still think that the question, in its current format, doesn't bring value to Stackoverflow by reasons I mentioned several times.

Comment: @karlphillip And i still think it adds a lot of value to the community. The post from Shog9 sums it all pretty well.

Comment: @linker I'll say this: I enjoy reading the opinion of people that have little-to-no-idea about what you are asking. I would love to see the people that share your point of view actually contributing with an answer in that question.

Answer (score -8):

I can't but help suspect that the primary purpose of the question was to garner a significant number of votes and a corresponding increase in reputation. Assuming that is true, one could argue it is the fault of the community that such an attempt actually works, and therefore it should not be moderated in any way. The problem is that most votes (again I suspect since we can't really tell) are probably coming from members who are getting a short-term rush from the dose of engineering goodness, and who are consequently forgetting that they are not upvoting a question but merely reflecting their rush. More experienced members know what they are dealing with and resist the temptation to upvote despite the rush. I doubt if their conscience allows most experienced members to downvote and thus neutralize the tactic of the OP.

If we had a "get to the point" rule, it could be applied. Do we have one? Do we need one?

I claim we need such a rule because that would allow experienced members to have a conscientious basis for downvoting and thus neutralizing the understandably high number of votes such a blog post in the guise of a question would get.

Comment: I can honestly say you that I don't care about votes, up or down. This is a **real** problem I've faced, I've explained it quite clearly with many details in the posts. I wouldn't have suspected one second that I would have gotten so many upvotes, I've only joined SO 3 days ago, I don't even have the notion of what votes are worth yet. I would argue that if I get so many up votes, it may be because the community doesn't see often enough questions who are detailed like this one, but that's just a thought.

Comment: Me coming to the OP's defense might seem strange, but I don't believe that the primary purpose was to gain some quick rep. I honestly believe the question is well intended and focusing on practical issues found. (My final opinion of the ultimate question asked notwithstanding)

Comment: If people are writing detailed, illustrated questions that describe a specific tough problem in a way that's interesting to Stack Overflow users all for the sake of getting reputation, [mission accomplished](http://xkcd.com/810/).

Comment: @linker, perhaps it doesn't apply to you but i hope you can see that the "get to the point" rule could benefit? Compare your question with so many others -- each question has an interesting story behind it. I am not suggesting to close your question, but to get the community to establish a framework for somebody who could abuse it. The key is "get to the point" -- if you can see that you can understand everybody's concern; if you cannot see it, it will seem unfair to you.

Comment: @Mark Trapp, sure, make SO a blogging platform rather than a productive one. The key point you are missing is that if every post were this detailed, far fewer questions would get answered. "Get to the point" is legitimate -- we edit/close questions for FAR LESS.

Comment: This finally sounds more like a question than an answer then. If you really believe such a feature/rule should be implemented, perhaps make it a separate question/discussion/request. Although I'm personally doubtful of its chances of success.

Comment: You want a blog post question? Look at that one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2297794/1332690 And yet this was created by one of the mods who suggested my question was OT...

Comment: @agks Like I said on the non-meta post, this is a senseless conjecture. The user is way too new at SO for a point grab to make sense for this effort. That's basically a conspiracy theory attitude and has nothing to suggest that it is probable, hence it shouldn't be believed.

Comment: @Bart, hopefully it is not too difficult to see that my answer is: "it is not constructive because it doesn't get to the point". I'm too jaded to put it out as a rule because kind of as you said, the SO community has a bit of a feelings-orientation which makes me too doubtful of its prospects.

Comment: @linker, I guess you don't appreciate "get to the point" -- if that rule were there that moderator's post would also have been edited down. You seem to imply that because that post was allowed yours should be allowed. You don't have to state it, but I would love to hear a clear opinion from you on what you think about "get to the point" in the context of SO which has so much q/a activity, so many intelligent users helping out everybody.

Comment: I just feel that forcing too much of "get to the point" would just turn SO into a homework site. I've been here only 3 days, yet I have seen a number of posts who were clearly posted by people who didn't understand what they were writing, yet they were upvoted because people just rushed for the easy reputation. Do you think it's better than clear constructive posts?

Comment: @EMS, it is not "proved beyond reasonable doubt" standard, but it is a reasonable conjecture, given what the typical new user does on SO on their first day :) Statistics are against such a marvelously edited first post. That said, the more important point that I have suggested is a neutral "get to the point" rule. It is perfectly objective, and has a reasonable basis. It doesn't matter whether I am right in my suspicion or not, and it can never be proved.

Comment: @linker, that's fine, we all have our opinions, and don't worry, nobody's taking the "get to the point" suggestion seriously :) I apologize for the suspicion, but that was the first thing that came to my mind and I feel that even if it doesn't apply to you it could for the general situation being discussed.

Comment: @agks There's no evidence to even deem it a reasonable conjecture. It's a completely baseless conjecture. Pure speculation with no grounds. It's amazing to me that anyone's even giving it the slightest credence at all. As for the 'get to the point' idea, I believe the OP did just that. Excellent background material that was needed for understanding the 4 points of improvement that the OP listed. Maybe it could be slightly shorter, but only with really nitpicky editing because largely all of the content meaningfully contributes to the question.

Comment: Also, if you think your own claim is not practically falsifiable, then why bother making it? That's very disingenuous. You're making a character ad hominem attack with no evidence. That seems pretty scummy to me. I believe you're doing it for the benefit of SO, but really it's hard not to think you're being pretty terrible by making a character complaint with no evidence.

Comment: @EMS, let me be precise, I strongly believe there is more than 50% chance, perhaps 80%. That's good enough for me to state it. You say "baseless" and "without grounds" when I have clearly given good justification based on what new users do. Your mixing up court-of-law standards with voicing opinion in a community. I have reasonable basis -- far more than you have to call my opinion baseless. There is absolutely nothing disingenous in my statement. From the very first sentence I have stated it as suspicion and there are ample unusual attributes of the post, and the number of eyebrows it raised.

Comment: @EMS, and please read your last post and your characterization of me as "scummy" and ask yourself honestly whether if it might not be more appropriate a characterization for your own self if one were to accept your reasoning for calling me that.

Comment: If you're accusing a person of trying to grub for rep points by making an appropriate and well-edited question, and you don't have evidence for this beyond your own speculation, then I think I can stand by what I said with a totally clear conscience. I dispute entirely that you've given *any* grounds for your claim. If you assign greater than 50% probability to the claim that the OP's question is about grabbing rep points, then I would say you have an objectively bad prior distribution on the event of a question being asked to garner rep points.

Comment: you are probably one of the question upvoters.

Comment: You probably also upvote questions that you think are good. Also, the sky is blue.