# How do you request a question being un-moved?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, migrated-questions

I recently opened the following question on SO: [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-shape-recognition)

It has been moved to DSP, while it totally fits the SO spirit.

I'd like to know how I can request it to be un-moved, as this seems totally wrong, more than 30 people favorited this question, but just 4 or 5 people disliked and yet it was moved.

Thanks for your constructive answers.

Comment: Do you not think DSP is a better home for this question? Why is it so important for you that it be moved back?

Comment: Please read ["On the boundaries of “not-constructive” questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129423/on-the-boundaries-of-not-constructive-questions), it's specifically about the question in question. DSP is probably a far better site for your answer than SO.

Comment: I don't care honestly where it is. SO has much more traffic and I'm much more enclined to get a thorough answer there. What I mostly disagree with, is this arbitrary judgement: look at the comments, almosst everyone was interested in the topic. Yet if a few people do not agree this gets moved. This looks too much like Reddit to me.

Comment: Everyone was interested, but nobody provided appropriate answers. A grand discussion certainly, but not the sort of interest SO is looking for.

Comment: You didn't even give the question a day and we are only US morning, how can you say nobody provided appropriate answers?

Comment: Hey, just got your email (it was linked to an old account, sorry to take so long).  Just want to say thank you, as it was very kind, and if you ever want to talk about SSF4 and DSP, reach out to me, and I can talk to you about some of the stuff I'm doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you asked it on Stack Overflow, and I believe strongly in [respecting the wishes of askers when their questions *could* be on-topic on multiple sites](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/), I've reversed this migration.

[casperOne made a reasonable choice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129432/how-do-you-request-a-question-being-un-moved/129433#129433) to migrate it rather than letting it get closed as "not constructive" - but [I don't believe it qualifies as not constructive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129423/on-the-boundaries-of-not-constructive-questions/129453#129453), and therefore have re-opened it on Stack Overflow.

You should keep in mind though, that there *are* quite a few experts on the subject hanging around [DSP.SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) - if you need help in the future, or are interested in diving deeper into image recognition, you might want to give them a second look...

Comment: Thanks @Shog9, I didn't know DSP before, I have several questions in mind who would be a good fit for there, I'll definitely post it there !

Answer (score 12):

I moved it over to DSP [as per my answer on your previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129424/140951).

At the time I looked at it, it had four close votes for being "not constructive".  As highly voted as it was in such a short period of time, it doesn't do anyone any good in having it closed as you'll get no further input to your problem and it will just sit there either as an eye-sore or until it is possibly deleted.

That said, if you're asking in general how to have migrations reversed you can do the following (in no particular order):

- Flag the question on the destination site for moderator attention
- Bring the question up on the destination site's meta
- Flag the question on the source site for moderator attention
- Bring the question up on the source site's meta (as you've done here)

It should be stated that while you might *think* a question fits the SO spirit, if it's closed, it's a pretty good indication that it *doesn't* fit the SO spirit.

As [per your comment regarding traffic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129432/how-do-you-request-a-question-being-un-moved/129433#comment353914_129432), just because you have a high amount of traffic on SO doesn't mean that it's a good fit, or that we are inclined to keep it on SO as per your wishes.  Not *every* question has a home, and your specific question was being told that Stack Overflow is *not* the home for your question.

Additionally, more traffic doesn't mean you'll get a *better* or *quality* answer.  It only means you get more traffic.

As per [Oded's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129432/how-do-you-request-a-question-being-un-moved/129433#comment353912_129432), one would think you'd want to get a *quality* answer to your question, not many answers which aren't of high quality (and to be quite honest, I didn't see high-quality answers on your question to begin with).

Finally, as per [the section of the DSP faq titled "What kind of questions can I ask here?"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/faq#questions):

> Signal Processing - Stack Exchange is for practitioners of the art and
>   science of signal, image and video processing.

Your question is a perfect fit for DSP.  That's not to say that it *couldn't* be a fit on Stack Overflow, but as mentioned before, with four close votes for "Not Constructive", it was being decided by the community that it was *not* a good fit here, so best to move it to a place where it is a *better* fit.

Comment: I can accept that it doesn't fit, but I'd like to understand exactly why. So far the only answers I got was that it doesn't include code, but the FAQ specifically says you don't necessarily need code.

Comment: How do you want to already see quality answers? We're only in US morning, you didn't even give this question a day.

Comment: @linker Your question was not constructive, plain and simple.  Sorry.  Also, we are not obligated to "let questions breathe"; the amount of crap that we filter through on Stack Overflow is massive.  We terminate things that are not a fit for the site with extreme prejudice when we see them, it's one of the ways that we maintain the quality of the site.

Comment: @linker "We're only in US morning, you didn't even give this question a day".. As much as I can understand your frustration, that argument falls fairly flat in my opinion. Questions which are flawed (to whichever degree) are flawed not matter for how long we leave them somewhere. That the US didn't have a look at it yet doesn't mean a thing.

Comment: @linker It is an interesting and creative question, I *like* the question.  I *upvoted* the question.  But the question is not constructive.  Asking "how can I make this better" is simply not what Stack Overflow is for.  I've offered you two places where the question would be readily accepted by the community, and yet you've rejected them outright.  I've moved your question so it has a place to breathe.  Again, I have to ask you, why the insistence that it stay on Stack Overflow?  You are hinting that you have motives other than getting quality answers here.

Comment: There is a simple reason: I have never heard of DSP before today, and I doubt many people have. My question will just get lost in the sea of the internet, and I will not get any answer at all that fits my needs. And for the third time I did not ask "how can i make this better", but "how can i improve it using this technology on these chracteristics". Please be consistent and also move questions like this then which are even more fuzzy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707607/what-are-good-algorithms-for-vehicle-license-plate-detection

Comment: @linker We are being consistent.  The current rules around migration are to not migrate older questions with accepted answers ("older" is subjective, but this qualifies).  That question will not be migrated over except under exceptional circumstances.  Your question was barely a day old with no accepted answers, and is a better fit for DSP, hence being a perfect candidate for migration.  That said, while not asking specifically "how can I make this better", it is what you asked in a general sense.

Comment: How is that worse than people who ask "How can I optimize my SQL query" without giving any direction? I at least gave very detailed direction.

Comment: @linker Finally, nothing is lost on the internet, quality content always finds it's place.  The content is just the same there and will get the same Google-juice.  The prominence in Google of a Stack Overflow question should *not* be your concern.  People answering are on the site already, they aren't searching Google for questions to answer.  Your focus should be on providing quality questions and getting quality answers, no more, no less.

Comment: @linker We close those questions down as well.  But Stack Overflow gets millions of page views a day, with more questions than you can count.  That said, there are things that we don't always find that slip through the cracks.  Fortunately, the community helps contribute with close votes and flags for moderator attention.  Everyone helps to keep the place clean.

Comment: I'll wait and see if I get some better answers than what I started getting on SO in just a few hours. But you're just encouraging people to post flat and dumb questions that can be answered with 1 line of code. Is that what you really want?

Comment: @linker I've not done that at all.  Please show where I've indicated I want flat and dumb questions on Stack Overflow.  You, however, seem to be hell-bent on having this question on Stack Overflow, or not at all, which isn't beneficial to the community.

Comment: I just want interesting answers. If I can get some on DSP fine, but my guess is that it will probably die out. I can repost it in a manner that fits more what you're looking for if you want.

Comment: @linker We don't want interesting answers, we want *quality* answers.  **Quality** has been codified in the site since day one.  Interesting doesn't always imply quality, although the two can co-exist.

Comment: How do you want to have quality if you dump my question in a forum where it will be forgotten before long? I did spend some time creating this question and making sure it respects ALL the rules in the FAQ, so if it was just "on the boundary" I wish you would have been considerate enough to let me have a **quality** answer as I'm doing my best to help the community.

Comment: And you're saying it is not constructive, so based on your reasoning it shouldn't be constructive on any StackExchange website. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @linker Your question was migrated, not "dumped", to a site which gets fewer questions as a whole--therefore, getting more attention than it would on SO.

Comment: @linker If you repost on SO, the mods might actually close it unilaterally.

Comment: I'd rather see it closed on SO and get some real answers on my email address without sharing it, than letting it die on DSP. At least in the first case I'll get some answers.

Comment: As @casperOne said, the goal is for *quality* not "interesting"ness.

Comment: @linker Um, you can just register on DSP and get the same email notifications.  The only thing stopping you from doing that is you.

Comment: @linker And just because something is an answer on Stack Overflow doesn't mean it's a *quality* answer.  I deleted 100+ answers today, and they were nothing more than link-only answers, pithy one-liners, or outright crap.  Stack Overflow is a great community, but it's by no means pristine.

Comment: @linker You mentioned before in a comment that giving a question a day on SO wasn't enough. Why aren't you giving DSP more time?

Comment: I'm just looking at the views and posts. My question is even number one of the month and it's been alive for just 10 hours !!!

Comment: @linker No, if it is closed on Stack Overflow, it can't get any more answers, no one would have been able to answer it.

Comment: @linker Your post got an inordinate amount of views on SO, too. Why are you complaining?

Comment: @linker You shouldn't post your email address in the body. That's not how SO works. Answers go on the SE site.

Comment: @linker All due respect, your concern here is on everything *other* than the quality of the content.  As moderators, that is our *primary* concern.  Votes, views, number of answers, are all *secondary* to moderators and frankly, should be secondary to *all* the users of the site.  If you are truly concerned about how many upvotes your question has, the views, how highly it ranked for the month, then I dare say you're focusing on the wrong things.  We greatly appreciate the contributions of everyone, but we want them to be here and contributed to the site for the right reasons.

Comment: @linker If you repost the question as an exact dupe (or close enough), then it will be closed as such and possibly merged.  This is considered *noise* on Stack Exchange sites.  Additionally, if you continue to do it deliberately, we might take further action to prevent you from generating noise (such as account suspension).

Comment: @linker You're not even giving DSP a chance, yet you complained that your question on SO was migrated too quickly?

Comment: I'll stop arguing, it seems there's no point trying to reason, especially since I'm now being threatened. Let me just say one last thing: I love SO so far, it's really great and the community is awesome. But when a few people decide for a whole community, it's called an oligarchy. I won't repost it, I think that would be foolish, I'll just let my question die in peace. I'll keep posting one-liners questions or answers to flat code questions.

Comment: How are you being threatened? It's not an oligarchy, it's a meritocracy. The people who voted on your question are all users with over 3k of reputation. They earned that rep, which meant they gained privileges on the site, which meant that they earned the right to vote on whether questions belong on the site. The mods did not take action without the community voice.

Comment: Without the community voice? With so many positive comments and some interesting answers that started to pop? No.

Comment: Questions about interview questions got a lot of positive comments and interesting answers too. And you know what? *They were closed*.

Comment: Was it to the level of interview questions? I don't think so. I was trying to make an interesting question, on which I did actually spend some time.

Comment: I don't deny you spent time on it. But that doesn't make it on topic wherever you want to put it.

Comment: @linker please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) You see the number of votes these posts got? Upvotes aren't all that matters in keeping this community together.

Comment: I don't care about up or down votes, again. I just wanted a quality answer, which I'll now never get.

Comment: @linker I don't have edit permissions on DSP.  I made a [suggested edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) to remove the rhetoric around the "not constructive" votes that were an aspect of the question on Stack Overflow.  They were not relevant to your question on DSP and were going to hinder it (since people don't want to deal with rhetoric about the system).  That edit was approved by *that* community and if you look in the [revision history](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/revisions/2077/2) the reason given states exactly that.

Comment: I won't argue. Thanks for your help on pushing this question forward overall, @casperOne.

Comment: @linker If you don't like the policy here, that's fine, but [trawling through my questions as a revenge tactic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297794/how-would-one-use-lucene-net-to-help-implement-search-on-a-site-like-stackoverfl#comment13062784_2297794) is a) sad b) frowned-upon by the community and c) will result in further moderator action if continued.  If you *truly* have a problem with the question, please flag it for moderator attention, or bring it up on meta.

Answer (score 6):

I can go to Yankee Stadium with a broken arm. I can go to the public address announcer and say that I need a doctor, and sure enough, they can send out a request for a doctor over the PA system and probably no less than a dozen will report to whatever location specified. Of course, they will probably stop and ask for directions a couple of times, but they will slowly get to me and with any luck, one of them will know how to treat a broken arm. There are a lot of people at Yankee Stadium (well, when the Yankees are playing), most assuredly a few of them are doctors.

On the other hand, I could just go to the hospital, where the doctors who know how to treat broken arms already are, and where those people will be immediately (relatively speaking) accessible. There may indeed be far fewer people there, but a far greater percentage of them are medical personnel.

You seem to be of the mind to go to Yankee Stadium because there are more people, when we are trying to direct you to the hospital, where there are more doctors. We have your best interests at heart. Why fight this?

Comment: That's not the point, I want to know why my answer was moved as it respects ALL of the points in the FAQ. No answer so far has been able to explain. Please advise.

Comment: Being someone who *actually* goes to Yankee Stadium 20+ times a year I can validate that your claims about Yankee Stadium are 100% true.

Comment: @linker You've been given many answers, you just don't like them.  There's a difference.

Comment: I have yet to see an answer to explain me in what fashion this doesn't fit on SO. I agree this fits on DSP, but there is no reason why it doesn't fit on SO. Or maybe you can elaborate.

Comment: @linker It was voted as "not constructive", as many have mentioned. And the people who voted were not mods.

Comment: If you do that, we will most definitely close and delete the question as non-constructive and *far* too localized, and then you will have nothing. I am sorry you don't find our system fitting, but we are not changing it for you. Find a Q&A site with a system you like better.

Comment: I like SO, I just can't understand how a few people's decisions can impact the whole community. Look at the comments, the replies, the votes, everyone was interested in this question. By acting like this, you're just killing the community.

Comment: @linker The community moved it to a site where it was a better fit, and you could get altogether *better answers*. It's not killing the community. The community is working.

Comment: Moving it to a site that nobody looks at? If after 10 hours of living, my question is the first of the month, I don't know how I'll be able to get anything there.

Comment: You don't have a "right" to get your question answered.

Comment: @linker Again, why are you so focused on where your question ranks among other questions rather than the quality of your question?  Who cares if it was first for the month?  Don't you care more about solving the problem of more efficiently finding the Coke can in your garage?

Comment: I'm just looking at the views, I don't care at all if it's first or last, but just saying that if it's first after 10 hours of living, then I probably won't be getting anything of value from DSP.

Comment: @linker I find it hilarious and troubling that you think **YOU** know what's best after a couple of DAYS more than folks who have been maintaining this site for many years.  I can't take anyone seriously who throws allegations of "killing the community" without actually understanding anything about the community.

Comment: Hey, I'm going to Yankee stadium tonight!

Comment: Ask for a good doctor.