# Don't preserve votes when moving posts between SE sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset votes on migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions)

I apologize if this issue has been previously discussed, but I searched for it and couldn't find it anywhere on Meta.

There was a computer vision question that was originally asked in [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/), and it got an **insane amount of up votes** there before it was moved to Stackoverflow. I know that **200** up votes are not much for certain tags, but this number is ridiculously huge for OpenCV, which is one of the tags of that question.

Please consider the list of the [**Top OpenCV answerers of All Time**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opencv/topusers): notice that nobody in the **Top Answerers** list (besides me) have reached the 200 up votes mark (at the time I wrote this post). If we consider the **Top Askers**, [the most up voted question in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv) got 50 votes in almost 4 years of existence (35k views).

Preserving up votes when moving posts to Stackoverflow is not fair to the native users of the site. Regarding OpenCV, the native guys have invested a tremendous amount of **time** in the past few **years helping others** to be able to reach that position in the **OpenCV hall of fame**.

It doesn't make sense that a post that came from another site, that has a completely different user profile/background, is able to put a user in the *hall of fame* of a tag **in a single day**. This question have successfully placed the OP in the 1st place on the **Top OpenCV Askers** with a up vote count that is almost 4x greater than the user at the 2nd place.

What am I saying? I don't believe that an up vote that comes from *Programmers*, *DSP* and other StackExchange sites have the same **weight** as an up vote from Stackoverflow (and vice-versa).

**I don't think we shouldn't preserve up votes when moving posts between sister sites.**

Comment: I feel like the motive behind your post seems to be personal rather than for the benefit of Stack Exchange as a whole, which probably isn't going to get much support.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Exactly. I would have supported this if the motive was different. (see bottom of my post below)

Comment: @Manishearth: Yes, the idea makes sense because it warps the vote counts on smaller sites, but in this case the votes came from SO (where the question remains). And now I see there is a fresh bounty - so I can't help but think the OP of [the question in question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168686/algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-shape-recognition) is also milking it.

Comment: @WesleyMurch About my motives being personal, I can't see a way in which upvotes in OpenCV threatens my work at all in this forum, I just don't think it is fair to the other users who spend years struggling to achieve that position. You would be surprised the amount of people that contact me via email every month because of my name in the Top Answerers list. Rest assure that people do watch it. And yes, I agree with you that the OP of that question is *milking* it.

Comment: @karlphillip: I actually agree with you, but there's something about the way you authored your post that makes it seem more like jealousy than genuine concern for the greater good.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Now you know there isn't.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Thanks for pointing it as a possible duplicate. I up voted the original question. Mine should be closed.

Comment: This is more often a problem when migrating *from* Stack Overflow, because the large user base inflates votes number to a degree that they are misleading on new Stack Exchange site.

Comment: As somebody pointed in a answer below, it seems that the question was originally asked in stackoverflow, then moved to DSP, then back here, then the bounty was set up, etc. People seem to be stuck in the case I described, but it was only meant to be an example of something that happens daily. I continue to think that votes should be reset when moving posts between StackExchange sites.

Comment: I agree with @karlphillip that votes should be reset when moving a question to another site. As should badges, I got several badges on DSP in the short time the question was moved there... Don't take it personally, you're most certainly more knowledgeable than me in OpenCV, I **never** expected so many upvotes on this question, I'd be happy to be off the top list or whatever it is if that's what you want, I'm honestly not here to be on top of some list, and I don't think that's the finality of being on SO but I respect your point of view.

Answer (score 4):

The question was asked on Stack Overflow, got an insane amount of upvotes, was closed as off topic, then migrated to DSP, were it only lived for 4 hours as the migration was rejected, and then it was re-opened on Stack Overflow. You can check the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10168686/revisions) if you don't believe me.

I remember a discussion on how ridiculously up voted the question was before it was migrated to DSP, and I think it's safe to assume that it got a fair amount of extra votes from the publicity it got via this [MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129432/how-do-you-request-a-question-being-un-moved) that chronicles the question's odyssey.

So even if the up votes weren't preserved, the question would still be highly up voted, it couldn't have got but a fraction of its total votes from DSP, after all DSP is a low traffic site (compared to Stack Overflow) and the question only lived there for a short while. And I think that would be the norm with *every* SE 2.0 site, it would be extremely rare that a question will get more votes on a SE 2.0 site than on Stack Overflow (in the same period). The feature *might* make sense for when a Stack Overflow question is moved to another site.

Lastly you mention something about some list, top tag answerers or something like that. Well, who cares?

> I **don't** think we **shouldn't** preserve up votes when moving posts between sister sites.

;P

Comment: People that hire through stackoverflow care about the list. And I've had my share of opportunities because of it.

Comment: @karl So? You still haven't provided any evidence that the question doesn't deserve it's upvotes. The OP made it into the top askers list the same way you did in the top answerers, via votes from your peers.

Comment: This case I referenced in my answer was just an example. It doesn't matter if all the up votes of this question came from DSP or just a part of it. I think that it shouldn't be brought along when moving posts from one site to another. Anyway, my question seems to be a duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions which has tons of up votes.

Answer (score 2):

> is not fair to the native users of the site

Oh, come on. Why do you really care about *others* getting in the Top `<xyz>`? I mean, it's a fun thing to acheive, something to strive for, and something to boast about. That's it. It's not "unfair" if someone else gets there--it's not a competition.

Votes are for the posts, not the users. Don't concentrate on user metrics.

> the native guys have invested a tremendous amount of time in the past few years helping others to be able to reach that position in the OpenCV hall of fame.

Really, I don't think "scratch my back, I'll scratch yours" is a good thing. It's just a metric. Don't get worked up about it.

I would have agreed with you if you talked about "the voting criteria is different". That is a valid reason to weigh votes--questions getting votes on one site may not be eligible for votes on the other, depending upon the faq and all (though in that case, the question shouldn't be migrated in the first place)

Comment: `it's not a competition` really? Let's drop out the reputation system in Stackoverflow and see how long it fakes the site to crash.

Comment: @karlphillip: It's a goal, something to strive for, **something to help gauge trust**. That's it. Feel free to work towards rep, but don't get too worked up about it.

Comment: `the voting criteria is different` and `votes having different weights` concepts have the same meaning in my head.

Comment: @karlphillip: Yes, and I would support it if the tone of the post leaned in that direction. But the tone is competition-related, and I oppose that.

Comment: I respect your view, but we are going to have to agree in disagree about that. I believe that this type of competition is healthy, specially to the folks that ask questions.

Comment: @karlphillip: Healthy competition--exactly. But healthy competition means that you shouldn't really care about some random guy getting 200 upvotes.

Comment: Then I guess we'll have to disagree on what *healthy* means. =D