# Is this question on-topic and constructive?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128086/simple-popularity-algorithm) describes a simple popularity rating algorithm, then asks:

> do you see any major flaws with this approach?

The description is very well written, and the question definitely shows research effort. But it seems to me that it may fit into the [descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583) of *off-topic* ("belongs to Programmers" [?]), or maybe *not constructive* ("will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion").

I believe it's a good question, and along with its answers it's a nice read. It's far more interesting than the avalanche of "jQuery to execute PHP MySQL query" I see every day. But should it be on Stack Overflow according to "the rules"? I really hope so.

**Clarification**

I'm not asking because the question is endangered (there are no close votes currently), but because I want to have a better understanding of the close reasons. As Yannis Rizos commented, this question sits in a grey area. I have a positive opinion on the question, I'm not voting to close it, but I'd like to know what others would do, and why.

Comment: Why do you ask? It's an open question, what's the problem?

Comment: No problem, I just want to have a better understanding of the close reasons.

Comment: That's cool, but... shouldn't you have picked a closed question? ;P Anyways, I think the question in question sits firmly at the center of the grey area between Stack Overflow and Programmers, I wouldn't close it if it was asked on Programmers, I don't think it will be closed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Yannis I guess that's exactly why I asked, it's in a grey area.

Answer (score 2):

The question is somewhere between Stack Overflow and Programmers, it's probably a tiny bit more appropriate for Programmers than Stack Overflow as it's a bit more of an algorithmic problem than a coding problem. However since it was originally asked and answered on Stack Overflow, it shouldn't be migrated, unless the Stack Overflow community decides it should be closed. And that's the general rule when there's overlap, keep good questions where they were asked.

The "do you see any major flaws with this approach?" wording may hint towards an open ended question, but it's not really that open ended, the OP did a fairly good job specifying the problem's parameters and I don't see how it's likely to solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. "Not constructive" applies when a question has little chance to build up to a useful Q&A thread, and this one (so far) appears to have build up nicely. I'd like some further elaboration on the one answer, but, that's not reason enough to close the question.

Comment: Good to know about "keep good questions where they were asked". As for "not constructive", your answer adds to my impression that this close reason may be more subjective than most others. [This thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129423/on-the-boundaries-of-not-constructive-questions) does that as well.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sometimes NC is clear cut: Polls, big lists, foo vs bar, holy wars etc. And sometimes it's a judgement call, that can go either way...